# What does it mean when a number is appended to a category?

Tags: magento-1.8, import, url, url-rewrite

I have recently imported with a .csv file with some products to a newly created category (created the category first), and the URL has a number appended to it like:

```
xxxx.com/catergory/sub-category-5
```

When I delete the number in the address bar, I get redirected to a different sub-category.

I've been reading about rewrite urls and truncating databases and other scary sounding stuff, but those seems to mostly relate to the products. When selecting a product from the category, it redirects to the product page with a URL like:

```
xxx.com/product-name
```

Using Magento 1.8.0.0

What exactly is going on here? Would it most likely be a problem with my import? Or the order in which I did things?

I would like to get rid of the number without having to do another import and re-adding the images.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

1) Would need to reindexing properly.

2) Url_Rewrite table need to empty but backup the table first then again also reindexing.

Hope this will be work.

Answer (score 0):

It generally happens when there is another same URL before adding or editing this new category (or product).
If there exists any URL, then magento adds a random number after the URL of category (or product) which is being added or edited.

It may happen that you had added a category (or product) with same name previously and deleted it, but URL rewrite exists.

To fix this, you need to take backup of **core_url_rewrite** table (if there are custom url rewrites also), truncate this table and reindex from System > Index Management.

Please let me know if you find any problem.